# Simple update table from multiple and/or new .CSV files

Tags: mysql, csv

Edited as it was considered too long

I have 1 table, 'customerdetails' imported from a .CSV and want to update it with a new .CSV file 'newcustomerrecords' with the same structure

Here is the code I have used which failed with the 1290 Error Code

````
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table LIKE customerdetails;

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Documents/MySQL Test Databases/newcustomerdetails2020.csv'
INTO TABLE temp_table
FIELDS terminated by ','
(customer_ID, first_name, last_name, membership_id, email_address);

UPDATE customerdetails
INNER JOIN temp_table Customer_ID ON temp_table.customer_ID = customerdetails.customer_ID
SET customerdetails.Customer_ID = temp_table.Customer_ID;```

How do I

a: update customerrecords from newcustomerrecords
b: fix the 1290 error

Thanks
````

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and focus on: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: *with a different name (first file is called customerdetails, second file couldbe called customerdetails220920) and what the code would be* Noway. MySQL have no instruments which work with filesystem - absolutely. MySQL may periodically try to load the data from the file with some definite name (which may be constant or may be built/calculated from some data, for example, from current date) into temporary or static intermediate table. If loading was successful then the data from this intermediate table may be processed by the common way and used for updating the data in working table.